# Fetching the latest row within a group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently utilising a series of tables within my TSQL database, which allow me to fetch information about a policyholder (or client). I need to group each policyholder by their DOB and Start of Postcode, as other matches aren't reliable enough.

The issue I am currently having is this will show me the maximum value within that group, rather than the newest value. I sadly cannot provide any data due to GDPR reasons, hopefully someone can guide me in the right direction with my query.

Query:

```sql
SELECT MAX([MSM_MarketPricing].[EnquiryKey]) AS EnquiryKey
      ,MAX([TotalNumberOfQuotes]) AS TotalNumberOfQuotes
      ,MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]) AS MarketPriceTop5Annual
      ,MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]) AS DirectInsPriceTop5Annual
      ,MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]) AS BrokerPriceTop5Annual
      ,MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]) AS BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual
      ,MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]) AS MediumBrandsTop5Annual
      ,MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual]) AS LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual
      ,MAX([MSM_YourQuotes].[YourAnnualPrice]) AS YourAnnualPrice
      ,'   ' AS ' '

      -- Number Prediction Calculations --
      ,MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]) * ((100 +
      (CASE
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 0 AND 250 THEN -7.09
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 251 AND 500 THEN -8.52
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 501 AND 750 THEN -12.11
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 751 AND 1000 THEN -14.63
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 1001 AND 1500 THEN -16.88
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 1501 AND 2000 THEN -18.00
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 2001 AND 2500 THEN -19.42
      ELSE -27.48 END)) / 100) AS 'MarketPriceFromBucket'

      -- Number Prediction Calculations --
      ,MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]) * ((100 +
      (CASE
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 0 AND 250 THEN -7.09
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 251 AND 500 THEN -8.52
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 501 AND 750 THEN -12.11
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 751 AND 1000 THEN -14.63
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 1001 AND 1500 THEN -16.88
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 1501 AND 2000 THEN -18.00
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 2001 AND 2500 THEN -19.42
      ELSE -27.48 END)) / 100) AS 'DirectInsPriceFromBucket'

      -- Number Prediction Calculations --
      ,MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]) * ((100 +
      (CASE
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 0 AND 250 THEN -7.09
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 251 AND 500 THEN -8.52
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 501 AND 750 THEN -12.11
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 751 AND 1000 THEN -14.63
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 1001 AND 1500 THEN -16.88
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 1501 AND 2000 THEN -18.00
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 2001 AND 2500 THEN -19.42
      ELSE -27.48 END)) / 100) AS 'BrokerPriceFromBucket'

      ,'   ' AS '  '
      ,CAST(MAX([MSM_YourQuotes].[YourAnnualPrice]) - MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]) * ((100 +
      (CASE
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 0 AND 250 THEN -7.09
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 251 AND 500 THEN -8.52
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 501 AND 750 THEN -12.11
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 751 AND 1000 THEN -14.63
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 1001 AND 1500 THEN -16.88
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 1501 AND 2000 THEN -18.00
      WHEN LEAST(MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([DirectInsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BrokerPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([BigBrandsPriceTop5Annual]), MAX([MediumBrandsTop5Annual]), MAX([LittleBrandsPriceTop5Annual])) BETWEEN 2001 AND 2500 THEN -19.42
      ELSE -27.48 END)) / 100) AS INT) as 'CostDiffBucket'
      ,CAST(MAX([MSM_YourQuotes].[YourAnnualPrice]) - MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]) AS INT) as 'CostDiff'
      ,FLOOR(ROUND(100.0*(MAX([MSM_YourQuotes].[YourAnnualPrice]) - MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual])) / MAX([MarketPriceTop5Annual]), 2)) AS PercentDiff
      ,CAST(CASE WHEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[DateOfBirth]), GETDATE()), MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[DateOfBirth])) < GETDATE() THEN DATEDIFF(yy, MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[DateOfBirth]), GETDATE()) ELSE DATEDIFF(yy, MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[DateOfBirth]), GETDATE()) - 1 END AS INT) AS 'Age'
      ,MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[DateOfBirth]) AS DateOfBirth
      ,MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[NoClaimsDiscountYears]) AS NoClaimsDiscountYears
      ,MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[LicenceHeldForMonths])/12 as 'LicenseLength'
      ,CAST(CASE WHEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, MAX([MSM_Enquiry].[FirstStartedDrivingCar]), GETDATE()), MAX([MSM_Enquiry].[FirstStartedDrivingCar])) < GETDATE() THEN DATEDIFF(yy, MAX([MSM_Enquiry].[FirstStartedDrivingCar]), GETDATE()) ELSE DATEDIFF(yy, MAX([MSM_Enquiry].[FirstStartedDrivingCar]), GETDATE()) - 1 END AS INT) AS 'YearsOwned'
      ,MAX([MSM_Enquiry].[CarValue])
      -- Sub-Filters
      ,MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[Gender]) AS Gender
      ,MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[MaritalStatus]) AS MaritalStatus
      ,MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[MainBusinessType]) AS MainBusinessType
      ,CASE WHEN MAX([MIU_BusinessCats].[FTBusinessType]) IS NULL then 'Other' ELSE MAX([MIU_BusinessCats].[FTBusinessType]) END AS 'OccupationIndustry'
      ,MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[MainEmploymentStatus]) AS MainEmploymentStatus
      ,MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[LicenceType]) AS LicenceType
      ,CASE WHEN MAX(CAST([MSM_PolicyHolder].[NonMotoringConvictions] AS INT)) = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS NonMotoringConvictions
      ,MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[AccessToOtherCars]) AS AccessToOtherCars
      ,MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[UKResidentSince]) AS UKResidentSince
      ,CAST(CASE WHEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[UKResidentSince]), GETDATE()), MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[UKResidentSince])) < GETDATE() THEN DATEDIFF(yy, MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[UKResidentSince]), GETDATE()) ELSE DATEDIFF(yy, MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[UKResidentSince]), GETDATE()) - 1 END AS INT) AS 'YearsInTheUK'
      ,CASE WHEN MAX(CAST([MSM_PolicyHolder].[MainDriver] AS INT)) = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS MainDriver
      ,CASE WHEN MAX([MSM_Enquiry].[FuelType]) = 'P' THEN 'Petrol' WHEN MAX([MSM_Enquiry].[FuelType]) = 'D' THEN 'Diesel' ELSE 'Electric' END AS 'FuelType'
      ,MAX([MSM_Enquiry].[BodyShape]) AS BodyShape
      ,MAX([MSM_Enquiry].[AnnualPersonalMileage]) + MAX([MSM_Enquiry].[AnnualBusinessMileage]) AS 'Mileage'
      ,MAX([MSM_Enquiry].[CoverType]) AS CoverType
      ,MAX([MIU_MSMSales].[InsuranceCo]) AS InsuranceCo
      ,MAX([MIU_MSMSales].[AreaGroupBandID]) AS AreaGroupBandID
      ,MAX([MIU_AreaGroupBand].[Description]) AS 'AreaBand'
      ,MAX([MIU_MSMSales].[HostedRatingEngineName])
      ,MAX([MIU_MSMSales].[CreditScore]) AS CreditScore
      ,MAX([MIU_MSMSales].[EngineCC]) AS EngineCC
      ,MAX([MIU_MSMSales].[Garaging]) AS Garaging
      ,MAX([MSM_Enquiry].[EnquiryDateTime]) AS EnquiryDateTime
      ,MAX(CAST([MSM_YourQuotes].[UsedGoToSite] AS INT)) AS 'Clicks'
      ,(SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) FROM [MIU_MSMSales] MSMS WHERE MAX([MSM_Enquiry].[PolicyStartDate]) >= MSMS.[CoverDate] AND MAX([MIU_MSMSales].[InsuranceCo]) = MSMS.[InsuranceCo] AND CONCAT(MSMS.[DateOfBirth], MSMS.[PostcodeOutward]) = CONCAT(MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[DateOfBirth]), MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[PostcodeOutward]))) Sales
      ,CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[DateOfBirth]), 3), MAX([MSM_PolicyHolder].[PostcodeOutward])) as 'UniqueCode'
  FROM [dbo].[MSM_MarketPricing]

  LEFT OUTER JOIN [MSM_PolicyHolder] ON [MSM_MarketPricing].[EnquiryKey] = [MSM_PolicyHolder].[EnquiryKey]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [MSM_YourQuotes] ON [MSM_MarketPricing].[EnquiryKey] = [MSM_YourQuotes].[EnquiryKey]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [MSM_Enquiry] ON [MSM_MarketPricing].[EnquiryKey] = [MSM_Enquiry].[EnquiryKey]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [MSM_Sales] ON [MSM_MarketPricing].[EnquiryKey] = [MSM_Sales].[EnquiryKey]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [MIU_BusinessCats] ON [MSM_PolicyHolder].[MainBusinessType] = [MIU_BusinessCats].[FTBusinessCategory]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [MIU_MSMSales] ON [MSM_PolicyHolder].[DateOfBirth] = [MIU_MSMSales].[DateOfBirth] AND [MSM_PolicyHolder].[PostcodeOutward] = [MIU_MSMSales].[PostCodeOutward]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [MIU_AreaGroupBand] ON [MIU_MSMSales].[AreaGroupBandID] = [MIU_AreaGroupBand].[Id]

  WHERE ([MSM_Sales].[PeergroupDirectOrBroker] = 'Broker' OR [MSM_Sales].[PeergroupDirectOrBroker] = 'Insurer')
  AND [MSM_YourQuotes].[ProductDescription] = 'insurance'
  AND FLOOR(ROUND(100.0*([MSM_YourQuotes].[YourAnnualPrice] - [MarketPriceTop5Annual]) / [MarketPriceTop5Annual], 2)) IS NOT NULL
  AND [MSM_Enquiry].[EnquiryDateTime] IS NOT NULL

  GROUP BY CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [MSM_PolicyHolder].[DateOfBirth], 3), [MSM_PolicyHolder].[PostcodeOutward])

  ORDER BY MAX([MSM_Enquiry].[EnquiryDateTime]) DESC
```

Hopefully this explains what I'm trying to achieve vs. what I currently have.

Thanks.

Comment: Surely you can provide sample data? It doesn't necessarily have to be the actual data, but you can change some details so that we have a better idea of what we're trying to help you with. Your sentence: "I need to group each policyholder by their DOB and Start of Postcode, as other matches aren't reliable enough." isn't clear because you mention grouping in the beginning, but then matching towards the end. Is it a grouping issue or a matching/join issue? Lastly, a `MAX()` function works the same as "newest", if used on a date field.

Comment: Hi @jw11432, I just need to group data and solely show the newest record and its data only, perhaps someone is able to look at my query and tell me what I need to be able to change to do this. My query runs, it just pulls random values out (whichever number is larger)

Comment: This is Oracle?

Comment: Microsoft SQL i am using

Comment: It's not clear what fields can determine which is the "newest".

Comment: Least is an Oracle function so must be a udf afaik

Comment: enquirydatetime is newest one

Comment: Do you need a `TOP ` whole row per group? Google "top 1 per group"

Comment: @Charlieface how could I implement something like this with what I've got so far?

Comment: Don't know as not clear exactly what you want. But roughly, you take out the `group by`, put the whole query in a derived table with a `row_number() over (partition by grouping_columns_here)` added, then filter on the outside to `rn = 1`

Comment: Essentially, I want to sort by EnquiryDateTime, "group" them by the UniqueCode and then only show the newest record. A policyholder can make multiple quotes, I just want their latest quote. Hopefully that clarfies

Comment: I'm really not sure you *are* using SQL Server here. LIke has been mentioned, `LEAST` isn't a built-in T-SQL function, and if it's a User Defined Aggregate Function I would expect it to be preceded by the schema the aggregate is on. You also have syntax like `WHERE MAX([MSM_Enquiry].[PolicyStartDate])`, which isn't valid; you can't have aggregate function in the `WHERE`, it would need to be in the `HAVING` clause. If what you have is T-SQL, then you'll definitely be getting an error when you try to run it. Though you do use brackets (`[]`) for delimit identifying...

Comment: Separate note, don't use string literals for column aliases. Use double quotes or the dialects delimit identifier (for example brackets (`[]`) in T-SQL and backticks (`\``) in MySQL).

Comment: Finally, all your joins are `LEFT JOIN`s, however, many are implicit `INNER JOIN`s. Either fix your `WHERE` (by moving the clauses to the `ON`) or make your joins `INNER JOIN`s when they are already one implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

**Sample data**

Just inventing some data. Going for a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```
create table client
(
  clientid int,
  clientname nvarchar(20),
  clientdob date
);
insert into client (clientid, clientname, clientdob) values
(1, 'Clark Kent',  '1938-04-18'),
(2, 'Bruce Wayne', '1939-03-30');

create table quote
(
  clientid int,
  quotedate date,
  quoteprice money
);
insert into quote (clientid, quotedate, quoteprice) values
(1, '2021-01-01', 1000.0),
(1, '2021-02-01',  995.0),
(2, '2021-01-05', 2000.0),
(2, '2021-01-31', 1900.0);
```

**Issue reproduction**

```
select c.clientid,
       c.clientname,
       c.clientdob,
       max(q.quotedate) as quotedate,  --> gives latest date :)
       max(q.quoteprice) as quoteprice --> does not give latest price :(
from quote q
join client c
  on c.clientId = q.clientid
group by c.clientid,
         c.clientname,
         c.clientdob;
```

This gives:

```
clientid  clientname   clientdob   quotedate   quoteprice
--------  -----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1         Clark Kent   1938-04-18  2021-02-01  1000.0000   --> not latest quote price
2         Bruce Wayne  1939-03-30  2021-01-31  2000.0000   --> not latest quote price
```

**Solution 1**

Suggested by [charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) in the question comments.
Number all rows (`row_number()`) descending on quote date in a common table expression (`cte`) and take the first row (`cte.num = 1`) for each client.

```
with cte as
(
  select c.clientid,
         c.clientname,
         c.clientdob,
         q.quotedate,
         q.quoteprice,
         row_number() over(partition by c.clientid, c.clientname, c.clientdob order by q.quotedate desc) as num
  from quote q
  join client c
    on c.clientId = q.clientid
)
select cte.clientid,
       cte.clientname,
       cte.clientdob,
       cte.quotedate,
       cte.quoteprice
from cte
where cte.num = 1;
```

**Solution 2**

Select all individual client info (and construct the client's unique key) and for each client fetch the single last quote information (`outer apply`).

```
select c.clientid,
       c.clientname,
       c.clientdob,
       q1.quotedate,
       q1.quoteprice
from client c
outer apply ( select top 1
                     q.quotedate,
                     q.quoteprice
              from quote q
              where q.clientid = c.clientid
              order by q.quotedate desc ) q1;
```

**Result**

```
clientid  clientname   clientdob   quotedate   quoteprice
--------  -----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1         Clark Kent   1938-04-18  2021-02-01   995.0000  --> latest quote date AND price
2         Bruce Wayne  1939-03-30  2021-01-31  1900.0000  --> latest quote date AND price
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=5da85f4ac9dfe4eadef776d754f2229f) to see things in action.

Comment: Hey, thank you a ton for explaining this fully! If I have multiple joins where data is fetched from other tables, would this change these solutions by much?

Comment: No, theses approaches should still apply. You can add as much joins as you like, but watch out for one-to-many relations. Example: if a client has 2 related phone number records, then joining with the phone number table will produce 2 rows for the same client. Another `cross apply` or `outer apply` might then be more appropriate to select a single related record (just as was done for the `quote` table here).

Comment: Thank you lots Sander! Just added this and ran, does it ignore all indexing? Query is on 35 minutes currently.. haha

Comment: OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 PH.[DateOfBirth], PH.[PostcodeOutward], CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), PH.[DateOfBirth], 3), PH.[PostcodeOutward]) AS 'UniqueCode' FROM [MSM_PolicyHolder] PH WHERE CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [MSM_PolicyHolder].[DateOfBirth], 3), [MSM_PolicyHolder].[PostcodeOutward]) = CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), PH.[DateOfBirth], 3), PH.[PostcodeOutward])) Q1

Comment: I cannot answer on that remark. For performance matters please post a new question. Make sure to include your _full data model in DDL statements_ and _a query plan_. That said: try to avoid functions in `where` clauses. Why use `concat(a.x, a.y, a.z) = concat(b.x, b.y, b.z)` when you can just do `a.x = b.x AND a.y = b.y AND a.z = b.z`?

Comment: Hey Sander, this is my current query https://pastebin.com/1ZYXe6RT it runs, though I still get duplicates. I want to group them via the PostcodeOutward + DOB, and then use 'EnquiryDateTime' from another table (thats joined) to only show the most recent one.